# Changing DataTemplate during Runtime

Tags: c#, wpf, datatemplate

I use a `ResourceProvider` as global management for my ResourceDictionaries. I register new ResourceDictionaries to the ResourceProvider and raise a event for each affected FrameworkElement. The FrameworkElement then updates its resources with the following method: (I tried several ways to fix this and at the End i tried to change the DataTemplate with its Uri)

```
public void UpdateResources(FrameworkElement elementToUpdate)
    {
        foreach(var controlDict in _registeredResources.Where(a => a.ControlType == elementToUpdate.GetType()))
        {
            //elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            //elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(controlDict);
            //elementToUpdate.Resources = controlDict;

            ResourceDictionary dict =new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/ApplicationCore.UITest;component/NewDataTemplate.xaml") };
            elementToUpdate.Resources = dict;
            //elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
            //elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(controlDict);
        }
    }
```

Right now when i press my Button to Change the DataTemplate the ui doesn't refresh with the new template. I have to mention that I'm not changing the object itself.

```
                 <ctrl:TreeViewControl DataContext="{Binding}">
                    <ctrl:TreeViewControl.Resources>
                        <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OldDataTemplate.xaml"/>
                    </ctrl:TreeViewControl.Resources>
                </ctrl:TreeViewControl>
```

My Question:
Is it possible to change a DataTemplate during Runtime and refresh the UI without changing the bound object itself?

**EDIT:** I continued testing: The ResourceDictionary (with its Template) is changed. A new added item (after the Template change) uses the new Template. But the old items are not updated. 
[image]

Comment: Not sure if [DynamicResource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dynamicresource-markup-extension) can help in this scenario, but since switching to new templates works it might be enough to just *"refresh the UI"*. Try to set `DataContext` to `null` and then restore it (maybe with dispatcher invoke).

Comment: Changing resource won't make any effect unless you provide composable parts in your datatemplate. (that concept belongs to control templates i don't know they work for datatemplates too) other than that you have set it directly as mentioned here [the right way](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/444371/Creating-WPF-Data-Templates-in-Code-The-Right-Way)

Comment: U can try with DataTemplate Selector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You could do it even with `StaticResources` if you reapply the template manually:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass1}">
    <Border Background="Green" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>

<TreeView Name="my_trv" DataContext="{Binding}">
     <TreeView.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OldDataTemplate.xaml"/>
     </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

But you'll have to touch the TreeView here:

```
FrameworkElement elementToUpdate = my_trv;
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/NewDataTemplate.xaml") };
elementToUpdate.Resources = dict;

var dataTemplateKey = new DataTemplateKey(typeof(MyContentClass1));
var dataTemplate = (DataTemplate)dict[dataTemplateKey];
my_trv.ItemTemplate = dataTemplate;
```

---

2) If you do not want to search your resources for a specific one, you could use `DynamicResources`. If there could only be one type of data in your Items, then it is relatively easy, you only have to name your template:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass1}" x:Key="MyTemplate1">
    <Border Background="LightCoral" >
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<TreeView DataContext="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource MyTemplate1}">
                <TreeView.Resources>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OldDataTemplate.xaml"/>
                </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

This way you do not have to touch your control explicitly in the codebehind:

```
ResourceDictionary dict = new ResourceDictionary() { Source = new Uri("pack://application:,,,/NewDataTemplate.xaml") };
elementToUpdate.Resources = dict;
```

---

3) If you have more than one type of data with different templates, then a bit of a trick is necessary.

First, you name your templates:

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyProject">

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass1}" x:Key="MyTemplate1">
    <Border Background="Green">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass2}" x:Key="MyTemplate2">
    <Border Background="Blue">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding MyContent}"/>
    </Border>
</DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Then, in xaml, you'll have to use `MergedDictionaries` instead of putting your `ResourceDictionary` directly in the `Resources` node.

Then, there is the trick. You put `ContentPresenter` inside `DataTemplate` set to `DynamicResources` with the correct name:

```
<TreeView DataContext="{Binding}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
         <ResourceDictionary>
             <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/OldDataTemplate.xaml"/>
             </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass1}" >
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" 
                     ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MyTemplate1}" />
             </DataTemplate>
             <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:MyContentClass2}" >
                 <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}" 
                      ContentTemplate="{DynamicResource MyTemplate2}" />
             </DataTemplate>
         </ResourceDictionary>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

The code-behind will change a bit:

```
elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Clear();
elementToUpdate.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(dict);
```